# Application templates and instances manager for docker deployment?

Tags: docker

I'm looking about application deployment with docker containers for production in some server (not hundreds). 
I can see some deployment managers like `docker-compose` who deploy according to YAML service 
description file.

Official `docker-compose.yml` example file:

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
  links:
   - redis
redis:
  image: redis
```

I'm looking about solution to manage/produce these YAML files and communicate with deployment managers like `docker-compose`.

This solution should permeit to manage Applications templates, deployeds instances of them, configuration of them, etc.

Illustration of it:

```
                                                         Docker
                                                    +-------------------+
                        docker-compose.yml          |                   |
+---------------+        +-------+                  |    containers     |
|  APP manager  |------->|Mysql_a|                  | +---------------+ |
|               |        |Mysql_b+-----------+      | |MySQL_a   |Mysq| |
| MySQL Tpl     |        |Mysql_c|  docker-compose  | +---------------+ |
| Wordpress tpl |        |Wp_a   |           |      | |l_b   |Mysql_c | |
|               |        +---+---+           |      | +---------+-----+ |
| Mysql_a       |            |               +------+ |Wp_a     |     | |
| Mysql_b       +----------> |               |      | +---------+     | |
| Mysql_c       |            |               |      | |               | |
| Wp_a          |            |               |      | |               | |
+---------------+            |               |      | |               | |
                             +---------------+      | +---------------+ |
                                                    +-------------------+
```

My thirst think is for [panamax](http://panamax.io/) but is it approriate ? Whats other `open source` solutions exists ?